# How do I remove the dir path from the powershell terminal in vscode?

Tags: java, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I want the terminal to just show a clean output of my code when I run it. I'm trying to get rid of the highlighted text in [this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTlv3.png)

I already changed the PS prompt in my profile to "> " but there's still some text every time I run my code.

Comment: it is probably a 1 pixel screenshot, most likely you can't get rid of it apart from typing it yourself, you would have a much bigger problem if it would not run

Comment: I think the command line used to run / debug your program is by design shown in the terminal; I wouldn't know how to prevent it from being shown, but you can clear the terminal from inside your application as soon as it starts up.

Comment: with what smaller command do you expect to debug your program no matter what the current directory in the terminal is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how vscode works, it will display the executed command on the command line. If you don't like it, an alternative is to use the [***Code Runner***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. After the installation is complete, add a configuration in **settings.json**, and then use `Run Code` to run the code, and the result will be output in the **OUTPUT** panel.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]